# GridView PageIndexChanging event

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview for which I set the boundfields as well as the datasource in code behind and on the PageIndexChanging event I set:

```
protected void grvList_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
   grvList.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;    
    grvList.DataBind();
}
```

BoundFields are also coming from the database, I have added them like this:

```
foreach (DataRow drColumn in dtColumns.Rows)
{
   BoundField bfEmbeddedColumn = new BoundField();    
   bfEmbeddedColumn.HeaderText = drColumn["ColName"].ToString();    
   bfEmbeddedColumn.DataField = drEmbeddedTaskColumn["ColName"].ToString();    
   bfEmbeddedColumn.ItemStyle.Width = 120;    
   grvList.Columns.Add(bfEmbeddedColumn);
}
```

It does show the records on the next page, but my problem is that each time the page index is changed it add the boundfields again. How can I prevent this from happening, it there a way I can solve this issue?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you have to move the following index to the variable e to the pager.

try this:

```
    grdSqlQuery.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    grdSqlQuery.DataSource = ViewState("dts_Sqlquery")
    grdSqlQuery.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to this. My problem was caused by the fact that on `Page_Load` I was adding the `boundfields` over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
        int count = 0;
        SetData();
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        ArrayList arr = (ArrayList)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];
        count = arr.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (arr.Contains(GridView1.DataKeys[i].Value))
            {
                Session.Add("PatientID", GridView1.DataKeys[i].Value.ToString());
                arr.Remove(GridView1.DataKeys[i].Value);
                Response.Redirect("~/EditPaitientDetails.aspx");
            }
        }
        ViewState["SelectedRecords"] = arr;
        hfCount.Value = "0";
        GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
        BindGrid();

        //ShowMessage(count);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

}
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindGrid();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..